# How to fill all other files to "false" when adding data into a table in wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress

For example, let's say there is a table which consists of 7 fields.
I would like to fill specific values to only two of them and set "false" to the remaining 5 fields.

For example,

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "imlisteningto";
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'name' => $_POST['name'], 'title' => $_POST['title'] ) );
```

Is there a simple way to set "false" to all remaining fields without specifying each field respectively?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set as `default value` for your rest fields to false, which means if you not specify them in you query they will be filled automatically to  default one

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do some search. Are there any references which I can refer to?

Comment: Here is the examples how to do that: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp